# Rails 5 nested attributes not saving update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I have two models with nested attributes. My form can update book :title, but not nested attributes. After I submit i see paramaters is going in terminal but there is no rollback just `(0.2ms)begintransaction (0.2ms)commit transaction.`

I spent whole day to solve that, i tried `inverse_of`, `optional: true`, `autosave: true` in models. But still not able save update. Also there is no unpermitted paramater error. There is another problem.

Model:

```
has_many :pages
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
```

Controller:

```
def update
  if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
    redirect_to @book
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, pages_attributes: [:id, :state])
end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.fields_for :pages do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.select(:state, options_for_select({ "close" => 0, "open" => 1, })) %> 
  <% end %> 
  <%= f.submit 'Submit',  %>
<% end %>
```

Example console result:

```
book = Book.first
book.update(title:"test", pages_attributes: [id: 124142 , book_id: 1, state: 1 ])
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  commit transaction
```

**EDIT**

Server log:

```
Started PATCH "/book/firstbook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-05 21:57:37 +0300
Processing by booksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"pElKKQq+M/5GuEG6nJ6Ac1vkEHyIknA2vPiDC9ND+50tq34nDtCRRX9k6TxaMZCInufp68m6BnO8jt4BsJ1bFg==",
    "book"=>{
      "title"=>"firstbook", 
      "pages_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"1"}, 
        "1"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"2"}, 
        "2"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"3"}, 
        "3"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"4"}, 
        "4"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"5"}, 
        "5"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"6"}, 
        "6"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"7"}, 
        "7"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"8"}, 
        "8"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"9"}, 
        "9"=>{"state"=>"0", "id"=>"10"},
      }
    }, 
    "commit"=>"submit", "id"=>"firstbook"
  }
  book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."slug" = ? ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["slug", "firstbook"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/book/firstbook
Completed 302 Found in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: Can you show us the server log when you submit the form?

Comment: I edited question. I dont understand why there is no rollback. I am using rails 5.02

Comment: It looks correct. Do you have any validation in your Page model? Could you post the full code of both models?

Comment: in pages `belongs_to book`.   in book model `has_many :pages, belongs_to :booklist, accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages`

Comment: are they on the same line? separated by "," in your model or is it just for showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try `f.fields_for :pages, @book.pages.build do |builder|`?
I'm not 100% sure this will work but I had the same problem with fields for a while back and this is how I fixed it.

Comment: thanks it didnt work but this worked <%=f.fields_for :pages, @book.pages.each do |builder| %>